# Reference on why a man is not allowed to sell female stuff

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, tafseer

I come across some of my friend one day, so we are discussing on many topic untill we came to this serious topic.

My friends try to tell me that they saw one Islamic brother and they find it amazing that he is selling **female make up**. So they ask is it even allowed, so from my own thing I say that is not right but they now ask for reference from Qur'an or Hadith but I couldn't provide.

So please him me with reference about that topic

Comment: "so from my own thing I say that is not right" - you should refrain from giving fatwas from your own 'thing' when you lack proper knowledge. It is permissible to sell cosmetics, even for a male merchant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to, [IslamQA Link](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/226184/ruling-on-men-selling-underwear-to-women), it is permissible for men to open a shop and sell women clothing. Now, let me teach you something simple.

I am very sure you probably buy things from Walmart or Gap or another other retail store that sells clothes. Now, women are the one selling the men clothes. The cashier may be a women, so what can we say here? Now if we were to turn this the other way around where men are allowed to be up front, then men are the only one left to sell this.

However according to IslamQA, a man can be a CEO lets say of the company, but leave the selling to the women. Or let's say the man has to do promotion stuff and it gets in the way of Islamic rulings on modesty, then it because non-permissible, otherwise as long as the intention is clear, everything is fine.

**Apologize in advance:** This post may sound a bit unorganized, well I am answering this not with complete thought in the early morning. But anyway, I hope this answer gives a good explanation may Allah guide you in the right path.

Comment: I don't feel like this answer is correct

Comment: @Muhammad If not, then go ahead and check out the link I provided. If you want us to say that it is not permissible so you can prove it, then I don't think we can serve you at Islam Q&A

Comment: @ Nano Adam, in my own veiw I feel like it may increase sexual intension of that man to females

Comment: @Muhammad, check this video out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEoi8X027RU. You will get a better understanding. What I am seeing is that your view currently is very high level, you need to build your view down to a specific view which builds your understanding.